# What is System.in in android?

Tags: android

I am doing the dagger tutorial for android in java, and they told me to create this class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    CommandRouterFactory commandRouterFactory =
        DaggerCommandRouterFactory.create();
    CommandRouter commandRouter = commandRouterFactory.router();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      commandRouter.route(scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote my own code to try to see what the scanner is pulling from, but nothing shows up. I am just wondering, if System.in is some sort of command line input, and if so, how would I see that show up? I tried typing in the terminal built into android, but that doesn't produce any output either.

Finally, where do you even get a class like this to run in android? I'm only used to having code run at least from the starting point of a main activity.

Here's the link to the tutorial - it doesn't help much with setting up
https://dagger.dev/tutorial/02-initial-dagger

Comment: That tutorial is unrelated to Android.

Comment: That's non-Android Java.  System.in is stdin.